# Converting words to hashtags when posting to Twitter

Tags: asp.net, twitter, hashtag, linq-to-twitter

I currently use LinqToTwitter to send posts to Twitter. I'd like to convert words in the title of the post to hashtags when it gets fired off as tweet so something like - "Firefox is cool" is the blog post and becomes #Firefox is cool http://myshortu.rl/dhsgeh on Twitter.

So far the way i see it is i need a database table with the words i want to convert to hashtags. I'd have to parse out the title and compare the words to those in the db and add on the pound sign. Is the best way to use a db table? Or can I do it with an in memory collection or keep the words in web.config? Thanks....

Comment: I would keep the words in web.config using like a space delimiter. Bring that list in and work with it in memory. Adding words to the config will be easier and make more sense than adding another row to a db and always having to hit the db just to get the list

Comment: Thanks that is what i was thinking as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision on whether to use a database or file (such as web.config) might depend on whether you want to write code that allows you to maintain the list. e.g. Add, Modify, Remove. If so, then a DB sounds like the easiest option. If the list is small and doesn't change, then adding a delimited list to web.config would work fine.

Since you're using ASP.NET you can't hold it in a memory variable, but you can hold the list in Cache. This can make for some very fast lookups, rather than multiple file or DB queries.

Just to put this into perspective though, it's tough to recommend a proper design in a forum because there might be details that aren't known. So, it's best to take my answer as something that helps think about what the tradeoffs are, rather than a definitive recommendation on what you should do.